# Just sync GMail-contacts with a certain label

Tags: contacts, gmail, google-contacts, contact-groups

Is it possible, maybe with some app, to only sync contacts from GMail to my phone if they have a certain label? E.g., I labelled all contacts from my previous job "Job1" while all contacts from my current job are labelled "Job2". I only want contacts from my current job, e.g., label "Job2", to sync to my phone while I want to keep contacts from my previous job, e.g., label "Job1", for reference, but only in the desktop interface.